# How do you use the TextChangedEventArgs.UndoAction property?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, undo

Ive just stumbled across property on a text box and it sounds the ideal solution for my validation routine, however I have no idea how to take advantage of it.

How can I use said property to revert the changes if the validation fails?

I have searched Google to no avail.

Thanks

Comment: Based on [this][1] reference, UndoAction is a readonly property. How do you intend to use it? [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textchangedeventargs.undoaction%28v=vs.85%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UndoAction` can only be used as a piece of information on how the undo stack is changed. To change the stack, use the [Undo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.undo.aspx) and [Redo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.redo.aspx) methods of the textbox.

However, you should use the [Validating event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx) for validation. E.g. in combination with an `ErrorProvider`. An example is provided on the MSDN page.

Comment: Thanks, for those that are following a similar line to me, this is my follow up thread with alternative solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115777/unable-to-use-undo-in-textchanged