# Unable to use Undo in TextChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, undo

When using textbox.Undo(); I get the following error:

> Cannot Undo or Redo while undo unit is open.

Now I understand why this is the case (because it is an active undoable event) but through what event can I perform validation on a text box and undo the change if the user has typed an invalid character?

Comment: You should be using behaviors instead.

Comment: SepehrM - could you provide an example? 

What if you do NOT yet want to validate but just want to stop this damn exception message from blowing up your session?  I am getting this when a user types a wee bit too fast or perhaps pastes a chunk of data into the field.  Not even validating.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of using Undo and TextChanged, you should use the `PreviewTextInput` and `DataObject.Pasting` events. In the `PreviewTextInput` event handler, set `e.Handled` to true if the typed text is an invalid character. In the `Pasting` event handler, call `e.CancelCommand()` if the pasted text is invalid.

Here is an example for a text box that accepts only the digits 0 and 1:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="BinaryTextBox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="133" Width="329">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtBinary" Width="100" Height="24"
                 PreviewTextInput="txtBinary_PreviewTextInput"
                 DataObject.Pasting="txtBinary_Pasting"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace BinaryTextBox
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void txtBinary_PreviewTextInput(object sender,
                 TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = e.Text != "0" && e.Text != "1";
        }

        private void txtBinary_Pasting(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(e.DataObject.GetData(typeof(string)).ToString(), "^[01]+$"))
            {
                e.CancelCommand();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, the "pasting" handler also validates if you are inserting characters using drag and drop.

Comment: Problem with this approach is that PreviewTextInput only previews whatever is being typed, and not the end result. This can only work if one writes a very complicated and unmaintainable algorithm to account for all possible inputs in regard to a valid value. For example, on a decimal field, try validating when a minus or period is applicable. Clearly, you can only type 1 of each, but not in every spot. Best solution is to validate the end result, _regardless_ of how it was typed. WPF does not have support for such, unfortunately.

Comment: Neolisk, you can cast the sender as a TextBox and check the CaretPosition to determine if a "+" or "-" is being inserted at the start, so you get.................. if ((e.Text == "+" || e.Text=="-") && (sender as TextBox).CaretPosition != 0) e.Handled=true;

Comment: Neolisk,  likewise, you could check if a "." already exists in the string, then don't allow another one.................... if(e.Text=="." && (sender as TextBox).Text.Contains(".")) e.Handled=true;

Answer (score 13):

To answer simbay's approach, which I think is being dismissed.

You can't call Undo in TextChanged because the undo operation is still being prepared by the TextBox.  It seems to work sometimes and not other times, so this suggests there is a race condition between when the event is signaled and the completion of the undo preparation.

However calling Undo invoked on the Dispatcher will allow the text box to complete its undo preparation.  You can validate the results of the text change and then decide if you want to keep or undo the change. This may not be the best approach, but I tried it and blasted a bunch of text changes and pastes into the text box and could not reproduce the exception.

The "accepted answer" is great ONLY if you want to prevent an invalid character from being entered or pasted, but in general I often do a lot more involved validation of TextBox input and want to verify the final text value.  Its not easy to discern the final text from a Preview event because as far as the control is concerned nothing has happened yet.

To answer Terribad's question, simbay's answer is better and more succinct in more situations.

```
tb.TextChanged += ( sender, args ) =>
{
    if(! MeetsMyExpectations( tb.Text ) )
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => tb.Undo()));
};
```

I've read a lot of wild adventures in text box validation and this is about as easy as I have found.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I still get the exception event when using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` method to call `Undo`

Answer (score 4):

Call the undo asynchronously from the From the TextChanged event handler:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => tb.Undo()))
```

Comment: How does this solution compare against the accepted answer?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I still get the exception.

Comment: I've figured out why it doesn't work for me. It was because I was calling `Focus` method on another control within the `TextChanged` event handler. Moving the call to `Focus` into the action body worked.